# NSOutlineView with badge of unread messages like Mail.app

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsoutlineview, badge, nstextfieldcell

I'm trying to create a user interface similar to the iTunes source list or the Mail.app mailbox list where a badge with a number (e.g. unread emails, new podcasts) is shown at the right hand side of an element.

Based on Apple's SourceList example, I have an `NSOutlineView` set up to display a couple of groups and a few items in each group.

Is there a standard UI element to represent the "badge" with a number for each entry? I could not find anything in the docs. I suspect I will have to extend `NSTextFieldCell` and do the drawing myself.

Are there any examples out there of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [`PXSourceList`](http://github.com/perspx/PXSourceList) by @Perspx and have found it to be excellent for doing exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has example code where they implement the unread badge using a rounded rect button.

See [Sidebar Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since a while there is a special inline button in the object library:

[image]